# How to generate tokens when user has logged in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, token

My app requires users to register and login to use the app. I am using Firebase auth for authenticating users. The problem is if an user downloads the app and doesn't  login, it receives Push notifications sent by other users which shouldn't happen. The user should only get notifications related to the app only if she/he is logged in. This is happening because the tokens are generated and stored immediately after the app gets downloaded.How can I generate tokens only if the user has logged in? 
This is the code I tried to use but the tokens are not generating at all:

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
@Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        final String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(REG_TOKEN, recent_token);
        //databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    if(recent_token!=null)
                        Log.d(REG_TOKEN, recent_token);
                    else if(recent_token==null)
                        onTokenRefresh();

                }
            }
        };



    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment this since I don't develop to native Android so i can't share much code, but what about sending pushs to topics instead of the token?

You could subscribe a user to a certain topic after he/she logs in or creates an account and send pushs only to people subscribed to these topics.

You can subscribe a user to a certain topic using

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your_topic_name");
```

So when sending pushs you'll only send to `your_topic_name`, and it's easier because you don't need to get all your tokens and send one by one (what i think you're doing).

When the user opens the app you'll need to check it again and subscribe him (just for safety).

Here you can find more about [subscribing users to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging?hl=en-us).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I want that all the devices who download my app should be able to get notifications about everything related to my app the only catch is that they should be registered to my app. Merely downloading the app shouldn't provide them with notifications . Same as Facebook until and unless you are not logged in you won't receive any notifications.

Comment: Subscribing to topics is not really serving my purpose. But anyways thanks for your suggestion.